# NullPointerException on BluetoothGatt.close() when the gatt object is not null

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

When I try to close my GATT connection, I do the following:

```
BluetoothGatt gatt;
...
private void disconnectDevice() {
    ...
    if (this.gatt != null) {
        this.gatt.disconnect();
        this.gatt.close();
        this.gatt = null;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the app crashes with a `NullPointerException` in the `this.gatt.close();` line (**not** in the `disconnect()` line) on my Samsung Galaxy S4 mini. When I remove the `this.gatt.close();` line (but keep the `disconnect()` line), the problem disappears. On my Samsung Galaxy S5 and on my Vodafone Smart prime 6, I do not have that kind of problem.

However, the [Android reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt?hl=en#close()) encourages me to call the `close()` function when I am done.

Here is the log message:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(26003): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(26003): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41813da0)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26003): Process: org.kolodez.MyApp, PID: 26003
E/AndroidRuntime(26003): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at org.kolodez.MyApp.ServiceMain.disconnectDevice(ServiceMain.java:575)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at org.kolodez.MyApp.ServiceMain.access$1800(ServiceMain.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at org.kolodez.MyApp.ServiceMain$MyBinder.disconnectDevice(ServiceMain.java:536)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at org.kolodez.MyApp.ActivityMainLayoutMain.connectDisconnect(ActivityMainLayoutMain.java:377)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at org.kolodez.MyApp.ActivityMainLayoutMain.access$1100(ActivityMainLayoutMain.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at org.kolodez.MyApp.ActivityMainLayoutMain$ButtonListener.onClick(ActivityMainLayoutMain.java:527)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4881)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19592)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
E/AndroidRuntime(26003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  785):   Force finishing activity org.kolodez.MyApp/.ActivityMain
```

Comment: well, can't you just wrap this in a try catch, doesn't seem like there's much you can do if that's the case

Comment: There are no other threads.

Answer (score 1):

this NPE shouldn't happened, it looks like some other `Thread` is `null`ing your variable... do you have anywhere in code `this.gatt = null;` line or `disconnectDevice()` call?

try below `try{}catch{}`es, packing up socket disconnecting/closing/dismissing into `try{` is pretty common (but not for NPE reason)

```
private void disconnectDevice() {
    ...
    try {
        this.gatt.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception ignored){
    }
    try {
        this.gatt.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ignored){
    }
    finally{
        this.gatt = null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have `this.gatt = null;` and `disconnectDevice()` in other parts of the code. However, I only have one single thread.